# Is it possible execute some action on thread failure in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, try-catch-finally

Let's say I have a Jmeter test which emulate some user login and several more actions. I also have 'start new thread on error' turned on. So in case some user fail - it will just get another user and keep processing the test for specified amount of time.

But I have some periodic calls for authorized user and to emulate them I'll need to use "Inter-Thread Communication" and additional thread group(-s). Basically this works fine in following way - in main thread I do login and fill some FIFO queue with required cookies, and obtain that cookie in another thread group. In that another thread group I do also check one more FIFO queue (that is filled on user logout), and stop that thread if get what I need.

The problem here is when main thread is fail after login. In that case child thread will be executed 'forever', since that periodic call keeps session active.

And the question - is there some possibility in Jmeter to execute some action on thread failure (smth like finally block). Basically I need fill that second FIFO queue either on logout or on thread failure

Comment: can't you use IF controller with javascript handling your required code handling processing after login failure.

Comment: no. since i don't know exact place where could an error occurs. problem is that i have lots of requests after login, and each of them could fail.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) at the same level as all your requests go. It'll apply to each of the requests and in case of failure you'll be able to do what your need.

Something like:

- Thread Group

  - Login Sampler
  - Some other Sampler
  - Some else Sampler
  - Beanshell Assertion

The example assertion code:

```
if (!SampleResult.isSuccessful()){
    log.info("Test " + SampleResult.getSampleLabel() + " has failed");
    // handle the error
}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for more information on [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I'm not sure whether this is a feature or an issue, but Jmeter functions used in beanshell are ALWAYS executed, even if they are in not accessible {} block, even if they are commented.
So having following BS assertion:
`if (Failure){
    //${__fifoPut(JSESSIONID,true)};
}

print("${__fifoGet(JSESSIONID,)}");
`
I'll get 'true' printed for all samples (doesn't matter if they were failed of not).

Comment: `Failure` is the property which indicates whether assertion failed or not and it defaults to `false`. If you want to check whether parent sampler failed or not you should use `SampleResult.isSuccessful()` instead as I mentioned in my answer above

Comment: It doesn't matter Failure or SampleResult.isSuccessful(), result the same - function always executed

Answer (score 1):

I also had to logout on sample error which needs something like try-catch-finally. An `IF Controller` with condition `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` and checked `Evaluate for all children?` as below, satisfied my need in a clean way:

```
TestPlan
    HTTP Cookie Manager
    HTTP Request Defaults
    ThreadGroup - (continue on error)
            HTTP Request - login
       IfController - (Evaluate ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} for all children)
                  HTTP Request 1
                  HTTP Request 2
                  ....
                  HTTP Request n
            HTTP Request - logout (after and outside of IF)
```